# Scrapy with deep navigation

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to web scraping, and I have a web scraping project.

If I have a website to scrape and the architecture of the pages on the website as follows:

```
A >a>b>c>d
B >a>b>c>d
C >a>b>c>d
D >a>b>c>d
```

and I want to extract the text from all the "d" in all sections (A, B, C, D)

this is my code, and it is for a single page, I have no idea how to make it for all the pages I have.

```
import scrapy

class LowsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'laws'
    start_urls = ['https://myurl.com'] #I hide the website url for privacy issues. 

    def parse(self, response):
        for divLawText in response.css('#divLawText>div>*::text').getall(): # the css selector here is to extract all the text from all elements under the main div "divLawText"
            yield {'lawText':divLawText}
```

is it possible with Scrapy to scrape deep navigation ? or there are other scrapers better?

Comment: I understand enough of your question to say that it can be done with Scrapy, but not enough to help you. Are A, B C and C start URLs? Are a, b, c, and d follow-up URLs? How do you get from A to d?

Comment: hi, sorry if I can't deliver my issue probably, but yeah all these representation letters are URLs and in order to reach to d page, I have to pass through all a,b,c URLs.

Comment: Why does your code not pass through them, then? You are yielding an item (`{'lawText':divLawText}`) on `parse`, which gets called for the response to the start URL (A?).

Comment: I'm yielding all the text that exists in the ''d' page from the A page only.

Comment: I don’t get it. Maybe if you showed example input and expected output it would help. Or maybe it’s just me, not awake enough at the moment :)